Does free enrichment preserve adjunctions?
I will use the definitions from Borceux's Enriched Category theory.

Proposition 6.4.7 Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a symmetric monoidal closed category with coproducts. The forgetful functor
$$
U : \mathcal{V}\text{-}Cat \to Cat
$$ has a left adjoint.
If $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category define $\mathcal{V}$-category $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ as follows

$|\mathcal{C}| = |\overline{\mathcal{C}}|$
$\overline{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) = F(\mathcal{C}(A,B))$ where $F$ is left adjoint to $\mathcal{V}(I,-) : \mathcal{V} \to \textbf{Set}$
...


In particular, I am interested in freely enriching over the category of semilattices and when I say a semilattice I mean a set with an associative, commutative and idempotent operator '+'. That is, I do not require a unit (the latter is sometimes called a complete semilattice). Semilattices form a closed symmetric monoidal category $\textbf{SLat}$ where the objects are semilattices and morphisms are homomorphisms. The tensor product for two semilattices $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ is defined as follows. $\textbf{A} \otimes \textbf{B}$ consists of pairs $(a,b), a \in A, b \in B$ such that $(a_1 + a_2, b) \simeq (a_1,b) + (a_2,b)$ and $(a,b_1 + b_2) \simeq (a, b_1) + (a, b_2)$. The set of homomorphisms between two such semilattices is also a semilattice where $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. This is similar to the analogous constructions for abelian groups or commutative monoids. The unit for the tensor is the semilattice with a single element (this is different from monoids and groups where the units are $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$).
In the above case the functor $F : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Slat}$ constructs a free semilattice from a set of morphisms by adding formal sums and quotienting by commutativity and idempotence. So below I assume that $\overline{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ and $\overline{\mathcal{D}}(A,B)$ are free semilattices.
Now consider an adjunction in $Cat$, $\mathcal{C}(LA,B) \simeq \mathcal{D}(A,RB)$ where $L : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ and $R: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ which is equivalent to having a family of natural isomorphisms between $\mathcal{C}(LA,-)$ and $\mathcal{D}(A,-)$, and $\mathcal{C}(-,B)$ and $\mathcal{D}(-,RB)$. That is, having
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}(LA,B) @>\alpha_{B}>> \mathcal{D}(A,RB) \\
@V \mathcal{C}(LA,f) VV @V\mathcal{D}(A,Rf) VV \\
\mathcal{C}(LA,B') @>>\alpha_{B'}> \mathcal{D}(A,RB')
\end{CD}$$
and similarly for another variable.
I am interested in getting a $\mathcal{V}$-adjunction $\overline{\mathcal{C}}(\overline{L}A,B) \simeq \overline{D}(A,\overline{R}B)$ where $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{D}}$ are constructed as above and $\overline{L},\overline{R}$ are lifted versions of $L,R$ using $F$, i.e. their action on objects is the same as for $L,R$, but whereas $L_{A,B} : Hom_{\mathcal{D}}(A,B) \to Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(LA,LB)$ the $\overline{L}_{A,B} : \overline{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) \to \overline{\mathcal{D}}(LA,LB)$. In fact, the overlines above $L$ and $R$ can be omitted since the action on objects coincides with their unenriched versions.
I expected that lifting the above diagram using $F$ would give us a $\mathcal{V}$-adjunction $\overline{\mathcal{C}}(\overline{L}A,B) \simeq \overline{D}(A,\overline{R}B)$. Clearly, the isomorphism is preserved by enrichment: if $\alpha_{B} : \mathcal{C}(LA,B) \to \mathcal{D}(A,RB)$ is an isomorphism, then $\overline{\alpha_{B}} : \overline{\mathcal{C}}(LA,B) \to \overline{\mathcal{D}}(A,RB)$ is an isomorphism. So the remaining bit is to check if $\overline{\alpha_{B}}$ is indeed a natural transformation. In general, an enriched natural transformation has a signature $I \to \overline{\mathcal{C'}}(F'A,G'B)$ for an enriched category $\overline{\mathcal{C'}}$ and enriched functors $F'$ and $G'$ into $\overline{\mathcal{C'}}$. However, for $\mathcal{V}$-valued functors (i.e. for semilattice-valued functors in our case as e.g. $\overline{\mathcal{C}}(LA,-)$) the notion of an enriched natural transformation is, as usual, $\overline{\alpha_{B}} : F'B \to G'B$ (Proposition 6.2.8 in Borceux).
The (enriched) naturality condition then becomes

Note the flip of the arguments at the bottom arrow, this is because $[-,-]$ is contravariant in its first argument. If we trace the component for $f \in \overline{\mathcal{C}}(B,B')$, i.e. for $f : B \to B'$ the diagram becomes

where the equation on the bottom right holds by applying the free enrichment functor $F$ to
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}(LA,B) @>\alpha_{B}>> \mathcal{D}(A,RB) \\
@V \mathcal{C}(LA,f) VV @V\mathcal{D}(A,Rf) VV \\
\mathcal{C}(LA,B') @>>\alpha_{B'}> \mathcal{D}(A,RB')
\end{CD}$$
Similarly for another variable. The freeness then guarantees that the square commutes for other morphisms of the form $f + g$ etc.
Is this argument correct or is it missing something?
In the literature, regarding adjunctions, I have only found the result that if $U(\overline{\mathcal{C}})$ has an adjunction then $\overline{\mathcal{C}}$ has one, given the functor $U$ is conservative. This does not seem to apply to my setting since $U(\overline{\mathcal{C}})$ is different from $\mathcal{C}$ (in Kelly's book).

doesn't this follow from the unit-counit descriptionof adjunctions? because 2-functors between 2-categories should preserve equations between 2-morphisms etc. Have you tried going this way?

Oh I'm probably being too silly, I'm thinking of the unenriched context and thought it would carry.over to the enriched case immediately, but after thinking about it it may not be so easy haha. Good luck.

@JackozeeHakkiuz, I've edited the question so hopefully, it is clearer and contains a complete argument. I do not know much about 2-categories, but should another approach amount to showing that $F$ is a 2-functor?
